# Javascript callback function for confirm bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I am using [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) for confirm alert box that I alert to user.  It is called from one js file and I have a common function where it is created.  How can I use callback function to get the result of the confirm dialog box:

So my js is as below:

```
 var message = "Do you want to close?";

 loadConfirmAlert(message);
 if (result) {
     //do stuff
 }
```

The loadCofirmAlert function in another js file then is as below:

```
var loadCofirmAlert = function (message) {

    bootbox.confirm(message, function (result) { });
}
```

what I am unsure off is how to pass this result value back to the calling function?

Comment: Or you can use [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```
var message = "Do you want to close?";

loadConfirmAlert(message,function(result){
    if (result) {
        //do stuff
    }
});

var loadCofirmAlert = function (message,callback) {
    bootbox.confirm(message, function (result) { 
        callback&&callback(result);
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Where

```
callback&&callback(result)
```

Is just a shorter version of

```
if (callback)callback(result); //if callback defined, call it
```

You can also use checking if callback is a function by using

```
(typeof(callback)==="function")&&callback(result)
```

Comment: This works nicely - can you just explain the callback&&callback(result); syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put that if statement inside of the callback

```
bootbox.confirm(message, function (result) {
    if (result) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

The problem you're facing is that your `loadConfirmAlert(message);` is not setting any global variable called `result` and so in your first code snippet, `result` is never filled.

Your problem is very well described in here [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) (although he is mentioning it with ajax, but you're having essentialy the same problem)

Comment: the if statement though contains fields that I hide specific to the page where I am calling the loadCofirm so I really want to pass the result back to that page?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat then take a look at mentioned [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or send `callback` function as second parameter to `loadCofirmAlert` as jevgenig has suggested.